# PHP & SqlServer Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

Can you help me please,

I use PHP and SQL SERVER.

I execute my stored procedure in PHP but when I launch it work but stop after few minute and I get the message error in bellow:

> Error in executing statement 3. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08S01
> [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 258 [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 11 for SQL Server]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258].
> [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Shared Memory
> Provider: Timeout error [258]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08S01
> [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => 258 [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure [message] =>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure )
> [2] => Array ( [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 [1] => -2147467259
> [code] => -2147467259 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
> Server]Communication link failure [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 11 for SQL Server]Communication link failure ) )

I show you the programm in bellow:
When I execute the stored proedure I get the correct result.

PHP:

```
<***$tsql_callSP = "{call [Test].[dbo].[store_pro](?,?,?,?,?)}";
$params = array(
    array(utf8_decode($Name), SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(utf8_decode($NameFir), SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(utf8_decode($adress), SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(utf8_decode($city"]), SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($A, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                        );
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
                    if( $stmt3 === false )
                    {   
                        echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
                    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt3)) 
                        { 
                            while( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt3, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
                            {..}***>
```

Comment: And your stored procedure is...?

Comment: My Stored procedure consist to get the ressemblance with another table in the same base.

Comment: Please help me I have this message error since 2month :(